# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Internal error occurred during: Worklight application builder

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

This is my first worklight app. I get this error when I Build All and Deploy after creating the project (without including any code):

> An internal error occurred during: "Worklight application builder".
>   Illegal character in path at index 5: /Todo
>   Project/console/api/applications/upload

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Worklight project or rename the current project so that there **won't be any spaces in the project name**. That is: "TodoProject" instead of "Todo Project". Deployment will then pass.

I have opened a defect for this. Thanks.